# changing the font to bold on a HTML unsorted list when clicked

Tags: html, onclick, html-lists

I have a HTML unsorted list which I capture its “on click” event. When a list item is clicked on I want to change that items font setting to bold so that the user gets a visual indicator that it’s been selected. Is this possible?

Comment: is it html <select> or <ul>? Please give sample code as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<li onclick="this.style.fontWeight= 'bold'">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

Or do you want to change it back to regular when another li is clicked? I think you should use jQuery then (it's possible in regular javascript but this is just so much easier)

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('li').css("fontWeight", "normal");
    $(this).css("fontWeight", "bold");
});​
```

Or even easier, just add a class:

CSS: `.selected { font-weight: bold }`
jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, lots of options, one of which is working great for my setup.