# Onclick bold selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, onclick

I have a HTML unsorted list with multiple "onclick" events. When a list item is selected I want to change it to be bold while the others stay normal. Is there a simple way to do this? I found this answer, yet was unable to successfully apply it. Can someone explain it further for me? [changing the font to bold on a HTML unsorted list when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768114/changing-the-font-to-bold-on-a-html-unsorted-list-when-clicked)

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: Im just wondering in a general sense how i can make a selected onclick list item event bold while the others remain normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in a "general" example way to do this with jQuery (as in question tags), you could visit a sample fiddle I just created http://jsfiddle.net/9gSf6/ or look at following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.b > li").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $("ul.b > li").css('font-weight','normal');
            $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
        });
    });
});
```

which works for `<li>` elements that are included in`<ul class="b">` element

If you're having multiple `<ul><li>` inside following would be better

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = 'ul.b li:not(:has(>ul))';
    $(select).each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(select).css('font-weight','normal');
            $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
        });
    });
});
```

Check an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9gSf6/3/

Same can also be done without the loop, like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = 'ul.b li:not(:has(>ul))';
    $(select).click(function(){
        $(select).css('font-weight','normal');
        $(this).css('font-weight','bold');
    });
});
```

Works the same: http://jsfiddle.net/9gSf6/4/

Comment: That is exactly what I've spent the last 5 hours trying to do, you're a genius, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

please look at the below code

```
  <html>
    <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(
      function() 
      {
      $('#list li').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('li').css("fontWeight", "normal");
        $(this).css("fontWeight", "bold");
      });

    });
     </script>

    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="list">
        <ul>
          <li> item1</li>
          <li> item2</li>
          <li> item3</li>
          <li> item4</li>
          <li> item5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This code will leave `<ul>`'s `<li>`s that are in parent `<ul>` bold after you click root `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript solution in case you want it:

```
var lis = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
if (lis.length > 0)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)
    {
        lis[i].addEventListener("click", function()
        {
            clean(lis);
            this.className = "bold";
        }, false);
    }
}

clean = function(p)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
    {
        p[i].className = "";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/zdRP2/